# Why are rewind and fast-forward buttons shown on MPMediaPlayerController when the content is a stream?

Tags: ios, stream, media, fast-forward

I have a MPMoviePlayerController as a media playback for a stream. Since it's a stream, there is no use of the RW and FF functions.

And the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MPMediaPlayback/beginSeekingBackward) explicitly say

> **beginSeekingForward** : If the underlying content is streamed, this method has no effect.

But it actually have an effect. RW restarts the stream and FF just seems to break everything (unable to RW or play).

So my question is: if the beginSeekingForward and beginSeekingBackward methods have no effect for a stream, why are they visible to the user (when in fullscreen)? And is there any way to hide the RW and FF buttons?

Comment: Have you tried changing `controlStyle` to [MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_37)?

Comment: My app supports both embedded and fullscreen videos. Embedded is fine but the FF and RW buttons appear in fullscreen.